# Is there a way to always pass in data across all render_template methods in Flask by default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Across all my render_template methods, across all my webpages, data is fetched from the database from a method called `fetchMappings()` which fetches data from my MongoDB database, and then returned as a dictionary to be rendered on my site. This is always rendered across all pages of my site. I plan to add a cache later on so my database load isn't so high - but that isn't what this request is about.

All the time I have to do:

```py
mappings = fetchMappings()
return render_template('pages/home.html', data={'mappings': mappings})
```

**home.html is an example file and this HTML file isn't always rendered*

Is there a way, by default, to always run the `fetchMappings()` function and pass it into data in render_template so I don't have to type this out in every single function? It's more efficient managed in one place as well so I don't have to do this every time, was wondering if there was a better, more efficient way.

Would appreciate any guidance, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Flask's [context processor](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/templating/#context-processors) to add new variables to your template context. In your case, if the Flask app is `app`, then try this snippet:

```py
@app.context_processor
    def inject_fetch_mappings():
        return {'mappings': fetchMappings()}
```

In your templates, access `mappings` as you would do normally.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I asked for :) And then you access it in the template as `mappings` instead of `data['mappings']`.